# Google Calendar Issues - Interface and Import

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have a app that creates meetings, i implemented a way to users sync others calendar by creating a .ics file.

The first issue is: When user receive a email with .ics file attached the interface of email ask to the user an accept box to sync email calendar.

But When the ORGANIZER is a google user the interface of GOOGLE CALENDAR does not shows the accept interface buttons, shows only the .ics file to download.

The second issue is the IMPORT method of GOOGLE CALENDAR, when i try to import my .ics generate file the GOOGLE CALENDAR not load the attendees.

Do you see any error in my generate .ics file, this work fine in Thunderbird / Outlook only in Google Calendar i have this 2 issues, this is a bug of GOOGLE CALENDAR ?

See my code and the generate .ics file

```
    public string RENDERMail()
    {
        //Monta o email
        StringBuilder lMail_Ics = new StringBuilder();

        //Cabeçalho
        lMail_Ics.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        lMail_Ics.AppendLine("PRODID:AV-Calendar");
        lMail_Ics.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
        lMail_Ics.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
        lMail_Ics.AppendLine("TZ:+00");
        //Abre o bloco
        lMail_Ics.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");

            //Adiciona os campos
            lMail_Ics.AppendLine("UID:" + UId + "@ambientesvirtuais.com.br");
            lMail_Ics.AppendLine("DTSTAMP:" + DateAdd.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"));
            lMail_Ics.AppendLine("CREATED:" + DateAdd.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"));
            lMail_Ics.AppendLine("DTSTART:" + DateIni.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"));
            lMail_Ics.AppendLine("DTEND:" + DateEnd.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"));
            lMail_Ics.AppendLine("LAST-MODIFIED:" + DateUpd.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"));
            lMail_Ics.AppendLine("SUMMARY:" + Summary);
            lMail_Ics.AppendLine("LOCATION:" + Location);
            lMail_Ics.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:" + Description);
            lMail_Ics.AppendLine("ORGANIZER;RSVP=TRUE;CN=" + Organizer.Name + ";PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;ROLE=CHAIR:mailto:" + Organizer.Mail);

            //Roda em todos os itens da lista
            foreach (TCalendarMail lAttendee in Attendee)
            {
                //Adiciona os participantes
                lMail_Ics.AppendLine("ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CN=" + lAttendee.Name + ";PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:" + lAttendee.Mail);
            }
            
            //Adiciona o campo
            if (Sequence > 0) lMail_Ics.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:" + Sequence);

        //Fecha o bloco
        lMail_Ics.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        lMail_Ics.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

        //Retorna os valores
        return lMail_Ics.ToString();
    }

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:AV-Calendar
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
TZ:+00
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:Meeting-93655@ambientesvirtuais.com.br
DTSTAMP:20200921T192500Z
CREATED:20200921T192500Z
DTSTART:20200922T190000Z
DTEND:20200922T200000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20201002T194900Z
SUMMARY:Reu Z
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:
ORGANIZER;RSVP=TRUE;CN=Pss Gmail;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;ROLE=CHAIR:mailto:test01@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CN=José Proença;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:otavio@uol.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;CN=Pss Gmail;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:test01@gmail.com
SEQUENCE:10
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Events imported via `.ics` file don't keep the attendees. This is intended behaviour (see [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/apps/_fGuUsUuHfk/STh7GEGuBAAJ), for example). You might want to file a feature request in Issue Tracker for that. About your first issue, I cannot reproduce this. Have you noticed this with different accounts? It might be a problem related to the specific account's settings.

Comment: Is easy to reproduce my first issue.

- Create a meeting in any app, google calendar not included.
- Be the organizer of this meeting with a gmail email
- Send this meeting by email to your gmail
- When you receive this email on gmail interface the interface buttons to sync with google calendar does not show

Comment: How to check this issue

- Do the same steps but not set the organizer with gmail
- Set organizer with any other email <> of your gmail account
- Put your gmail account as a attendee
- Send the email and see that interface buttons to sync show in the email

Comment: By `I cannot reproduce` I meant that I followed all the steps you mentioned and didn't experience the same behaviour as you. In my case, it didn't matter that the user was the organizer or not: the "accept box" was always present. That's why I asked you if you noticed this with different accounts. So, have you noticed this behaviour with different accounts? What type of account do you have?